# how can I solve this logarithmic equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I've tried NSolve, Solve and Reduce for solving this equation but non of them worked. would you please help me?

```
NSolve[Log[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x])] == 3 Sqrt[1 - x], x]
NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.
```

Comment: The closest your left-hand-side ever gets to your right-hand-side is for $x=1$; but there is no actual solution for $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There does not seem to be solution in the reals. `Solve[Log[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x])] - 3 Sqrt[1 - x] == 0 && -100 <= x <= 100, x, Reals]` gives {}

Comment: Looks ill-posed: there would be a real solution if another branch of square root were chosen on the right side and maybe others if other branches on the left are chosen as well.

Answer (score 6):

Divide by "Sqrt[1-x]" and define the function:

```
f[x_] = 1/Sqrt[1 - x] Log[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x])]
```

Now check the behavior of this function. It will be concentrated around 0 and 1. Note the phase as indicated by the legend:

```
ComplexPlot3D[f[x], {x, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You see that the function comes nowhere near +3. It would be red and have a magnitude of 3. Therefore, your equation has no solution in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fixed point iteration:

```
(* First find a suitable rearrangement by replacing an x with c and solve *)
eqn = Log[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x])] == 3 Sqrt[1 - c];

(* 1/9 (9 - Log[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x])]^2) *)

(* Now find a fixed point if one exists *)
FixedPoint[1 - (Log[Sqrt[#]/(1 + Sqrt[#])]/3)^2 &, 1.0, 50]

(* 0.9443735327111197` *)

(* Try it out on both sides: *)
Log[Sqrt[0.9443735327111197`]/(1 + Sqrt[0.9443735327111197`])]
(* -0.707558 *)

3 Sqrt[1 - 0.9443735327111197`]
(* 0.707558 *)
```

So as you can see, @josh 's comment about the branches is right, as the `Sqrt` on the right hand side is using the negative square root. This agrees with `FindInstance` if you square both sides:

```
x /. First@FindInstance[9 (1 - x) == Log[1 - 1/(1 + Sqrt[x])]^2, x]
(* Root[{9 - Log[1 - (1 + #^Rational[1, 2])^(-1)]^2 - 9 #& , 
  0.9443735327111196808405153254286572521300613203544128514706`30.15051499783199}] *)
```